# Simple C program involving arrays cannot execute

Tags: c

I have a homework problem which requires me to convert a word a user entered to Pig Latin by moving the first letter of the word to the end and adding an ay to it. For example, Tuesday becomes uesdayTay. This process should be repeated until the user types STOP.

I'm really new to arrays, so I might be using them wrongly, but I can't find out why. The program I wrote can be compiled but crashes whenever I execute it. I'm sure this program is rather simple, but here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char *input_word [100], *temp [100], *stop [4];
    int n = 0;

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    for( n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    { 
        scanf("%s", input_word[n]);
    }


    while (  strcmp ( stop [4], "STOP" ) != 0 )
    {
        *temp = input_word [0];
        for ( int j = 1; j <= n-1; j++)
        {
            *input_word [j-1] = *input_word [j];
        }

        input_word [n-1] = *temp;

        printf("%s", *input_word);
        printf("ay\n");

        printf("Type STOP to terminate: ");
        for ( n = 0; n < 4; n++ )
        {
            scanf("%s", stop[n] );
        }

    }

    return 0;


}
```

Can anyone please help me out? I find arrays to be rather confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Where does `stop [4]` get initialized?

Comment: Please include *where* does it crash? With what input ?

Comment: You have to initialize `input_word`, otherwise the pointers point to nothing.

Comment: To use pointers well you **always** have to know where they point to. Your `input_word` is an array of 100 pointers. None of those pointers points anywhere valid. The same for `temp` and `stop` which is an array of 4 pointers.

Comment: Hint: you don't really need pointers (other than the automatic conversion between arrays and pointers) for what you want to do.

Comment: @Yuriy Ivaskevych It crashes right after I typed in a word

Comment: Well, after initializing the arrays, the program still crashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", input_word[n])
```

I will stop you already there.

You declared input_word as an array of pointers, but those pointers are 1. not initialized 2. not pointing to valid memory that you need to allocate.

Instead first declare an array to hold the input from the user

```
char input_word[100];
```

Now to keep things simple, use fgets to read from the command line

```
fgets(input_word, sizeof(input_word), stdin);
```

Now remove the trailing \n if any:

```
 char* p = strchr(input_word, '\n'); 
 if (p) 
 {
   *p = '\0';
 }
```

Now you have "Tuesday\0" (if you entered that word) in input_word.

Have another array for the new word:

```
char output_word[100] = { '\0' };
```

Skip the first character and copy until end of string:

```
strcpy(output_word, input_word + 1);
```

Now take the first character and add it:

```
strncat(output_word, input_word, 1);
```

Then add the rest using strcat, and sprinkle code with checks like length of string entered.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, there's lots I don't understand about your answer. Did you initialize output_word with '\0', so that in in case the word size is smaller than array size declared, the zeroes filled in by compiler would not get mized up with the word? And why must you skip the first two characters in a string and copy the rest? And why add the first two characters?

Comment: @LimLS technically there is no need to initialize output_word since strcpy will overwrite the contents. Skipping one char was because in your assignment you were supposed to copy them to the end of the string, I showed skipping two since I misread your assignment.